# Renaming project in Xcode 4.2

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.2

Recently I upgraded Xcode from 3.2.5 to 4.2.  When it was necessary I changed name of project by "slowly clicking 2 times" on blue project icon, which in turn gave me list of other files whose name can be changed. I changed name of all the files(including product name).

But now problem is when build is archived it is saved with previous name of project. Does anyone have idea what might be the problem.

Comment: Please check projectname-info.plist file and see if there is an entry with old project name there.

Comment: Thanks Rahul for your suggestion. solution given by Nekto worked fine for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this one:

```
Product -> Edit Scheme... -> Archive/Release -> Archive Name -> ???
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. this is the the thing I was looking after. I don't understand why don't Xcode rename all the necessary things by itself. in Xcode 3.x.x there is no such problem. you just rename the project and it takes care of all things. again thanks a lot..